# How to Resolve Circular dependency interface in constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
public class Logger : ILogger
{
    private readonly ILoggerHandler LoggerH;      
    public Logger(ILoggerHandler _LoggerH)
    {
        LoggerH = _LoggerH;           
    }


    public async Task exception(LogObj _log)
    { 
        await LoggerH.Log(_log); // Called ILoggerHandler Method
    } 
}



public interface ILogger
{      
    Task exception(LogObj _log);       
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public interface ILoggerHandler
{
    Task Log(LogObj log);
}



public class LoggerHandler: ILoggerHandler
{

    private readonly IAPIHandler _apiHandler;


    public LoggerHandler(IAPIHandler apiHandler)
    {
        _apiHandler = apiHandler;

    }



    public async Task Log(LogObj log)
    {
        try
        {               
     var request = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(log);                
     await _apiHandler.Process(request, url, HttpMethode.POST, _headers); // Called IAPIHandler Method
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }     

}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public interface IAPIHandler
{
    Task<string> Process(string Request, string RequestURL, string httpMethode, Dictionary<string, string> Header = null);
}





public class APIHandler : IAPIHandler
{
    private readonly DateTime requestTime;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public APIHandler(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        this.requestTime = DateTime.Now;
    }


    public async Task<string> Process(string Request, string RequestURL, string httpMethode, Dictionary<string, string> Header = null)
    {
        string content = string.Empty;
        try
        {
           // code for calling the service(Logger)
        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {
            content = "Error";
            var response = wex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            await _logger.exception(wex, Request, this.requestTime);  // Called ILogger Method
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            content = "Error";
            await _logger.exception(ex, Request, this.requestTime);
        }
        return content;
    }
```

1. **ILogger** consist of method **exception** which Log the error whenever the exception occur in the code
2. exception method in **ILogger** call the method Log in **ILoggerHandler**
   which call the log service
3. **ILoggerHandler** call **IAPIHandler** to invoke the service
4. To log the exception in **IAPIHandler** again **ILogger** exception method is called

so this leads to circular dependency so need help in resolving this

Comment: According to me, there is a clear desin flaw indeed.
Why do you need this particular design ? 
The simplest fix would be that process of log, would be done in Logger class.
If you need an external notification in cas, trigger a notification from an external service that only sends the notification.

Comment: Why on earth you want to invent yet another logger? https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/WebService-target

Comment: Logger will have only utility function such as  log,info the Api calling part require LoggerHandler